# Как воспроизвести или иницировать воспроизведение MP3 посредством JS на iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios

Имеется следующая строка:

```
<audio id="sound">
  <source src="/view/assets/sound/notify.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Воспроизведение дорожки происходит когда AJAX запрос отправляет текст NEW_NOTIFY:

```
setInterval(() => {
$.ajax({
url: "/api?wnotify",
type: "get",
success: function(response){
if (response.includes("NEW_NOTIFY")){
$(function(){
    $('#sound').get(0).play();
});
}
}
});
}, 2000);
```

данная реализация работает на всех браузерах ПК и Мобильного если первый тап совершен со стороны ЮЗЕРА, но реализация не работает на iOS как решить эту задачу? Как переписать или добавить строку кода чтобы и на iOS заработало?

Comment: Не работает воспроизведение или не работает setInterval? Вы проверяли как-нибудь, отрабатывает ли setInterval вообще?

Comment: Да и в общем - а доходит ли выполнение до setInterval вообще? Вдруг где-то раньше в коде есть ошибка, прерывающая дальнейшее выполнение?

Comment: Тег **source** нужно закрывать.

Comment: А что за **$('#sound').get(0).play();**? Попробуйте **$('#sound').play();** У аудио нет метода **get**.